# How can I call a function action anywhere on a form?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, action

I have a function that shows the uploaded avatar and remove button in case you want to delete the avatar. Everything works correctly. My problem is that the displayed avatar and remove button are merged together, if I want to move the remove button somewhere else I can't do it.

So I'm looking for a way to call the remove button wherever I want. I was thinking of js solutions to change the html structure as a last hope and solution, but I don't want to do that.

Anyone have any ideas on how I could move the remove button elsewhere? The function is located in functions.php, the destination I should move the button to is the form-edit-account.php template which I customized to my needs.

**The line i want to move is this**:

```
echo '<a href=' . wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') . '?rm_profile_image_id=' . $attachment_id . '> ' . __('Remove') . ' </a>';
```

**This is a complete function**:

```
// Display / Remove Avatar
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form($size) {

  // Get current user id
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();

  // Get attachment id
  $attachment_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'image', true);

  // True
  if ($attachment_id) {
    $original_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);

    // Display Image instead of URL
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $size = array('150', '150')); // Invece dell'array size, stava 'full' come parametro.

    if (isset($_GET['rm_profile_image_id'])) {
      if ($attachment_id == $_GET['rm_profile_image_id']) {
        wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
        
        //delete_user_meta($user_id, 'image');
        if (delete_user_meta($user_id, 'image')) {
          wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
        }

        ?><script>window.location='<?php echo wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') ?>';</script><?php
        exit();
      }
    } else {
      echo '<a href=' . wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') . '?rm_profile_image_id=' . $attachment_id . '> ' . __('Remove') . ' </a>';
    }
  }
} add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's weird but it works, I put the function directly inside the form. It's not a very "clean" solution, but it's working for me. If anyone thinks I am doing something wrong I appreciate any suggestions and corrections.

```
<form name="Form" class="mts-edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> >
  
  <!-- Avatar Remove button -->
  <div class="global_container avatar">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['rm_profile_image_id'])) {
      if ($attachment_id == $_GET['rm_profile_image_id']) {
        wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
        
        //delete_user_meta($user_id, 'image');
        if (delete_user_meta($user_id, 'image')) {
          wp_delete_attachment($attachment_id);
        }

        ?><script>window.location='<?php echo wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') ?>';</script><?php
        exit();
      }
    } else {
      echo '<a href=' . wc_get_account_endpoint_url('impostazioni') . '?rm_profile_image_id=' . $attachment_id . '> ' . __('Remove') . ' </a>';
    } ?>
  </div>  

//Other fields........

</form>
```